# Chained method calls: Chop down if long causes strange effects with constructors/functions with many parameters?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I like using intellij idea for my daily work, but since i got into the new java stuff like streams and builder one thing has bugged me.

When i set the java code style setting "Chained method calls" to "Chop down if long" my constructor:

```
public Blog(Blog c) {
    this(c.getId(), c.getFromId(), c.getSiteId(), c.getUserId(), c.getTitle(), c.getFolder(), c.getAddedDate(), c.getFrontPos(), c.isUseSiteWidgets(), c
      .isNeedValidSubscriptionToView(), c.isMayStudentPostComments(), c.getLastIndexDate(), c.isCommentsEnabled(), c.isOverrideSiteSettings(), c
      .isNotifyOnComment(), c.isOnlyNotiftyOnUnapprovedComment());
  }
```

becomes:

```
public Blog(Blog c) {
    this(c.getId(), c.getFromId(), c.getSiteId(), c.getUserId(), c.getTitle(), c.getFolder(), c.getAddedDate(), c.getFrontPos(), c.isUseSiteWidgets(), c
      .isNeedValidSubscriptionToView(), c
      .isMayStudentPostComments(), c.getLastIndexDate(), c.isCommentsEnabled(), c.isOverrideSiteSettings(), c.isNotifyOnComment(), c
      .isOnlyNotiftyOnUnapprovedComment());
  }
```

When i set  "Chained method calls" to "Do not wrap" my builder method calls become very confusing. From:

```
getWizard().sendCommandToServer(CommandProtos.Wrapper.newBuilder()
          .setGetTutorSites(CommandProtos.GetTutorSites.newBuilder()
            .setEmail(loginUserForm.getEmail().getText())
            .setPass(new String(loginUserForm.getPass().getPassword()))
            .build())
          .build());
```

to a one liner:

```
getWizard().sendCommandToServer(CommandProtos.Wrapper.newBuilder().setGetTutorSites(CommandProtos.GetTutorSites.newBuilder().setEmail(loginUserForm
          .getEmail().getText()).setPass(new String(loginUserForm.getPass().getPassword())).build()).build());
```

Is it possible to get the best from both worlds? In other words a correctly formatted function/constructor with many parameters and a correctly formated builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just gave the new idea 2018.4 a try and it seems that setting "Chained method calls" to "wrap always" and disabling "wrap first call" and "align when multiline" is the solution.

Now chains and long constructors format correctly. Hope this helps people with similar problems.

**[edit]**
The above did work nicely, until you find yourself calling something like:

```
myclass.myfunc().myfunc()
```

This seem to be common when working with swing. The above settings result in:

```
myclass.myfunc()
.myfunc()
```

"Chained method calls" to "chop down if long" and disabling "wrap first call" and "align when multiline" and also set "method call arguments" to "wrap if long" (needed for long constructors) does the job.

Code style per module might solve a lot of these problems, but it's not in intellij, but you can vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69685